# How to add polygon points and draw it on an image in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

This code is supportable in fabric js version 1.5 but it not supported in latest version of fabric js like 1.7 and higher.Can anybody help me out in this code.I want this to be implemented in fabric version 1.7.21.Whats the changes made in mouse coordinates in the newer version of the fabric.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var polygonCount = 1;
var startDrawingPolygon;
var ArrayLength;
var addTexture = false;
var circleCount = 1;
var fillColor = "rgba(46, 240, 56, 0.5)";

function done() {
  startDrawingPolygon = false;
  ArrayLength = circleCount;
  circleCount = 1;
  var tempCount = 0;
  window["polygon" + polygonCount] = new fabric.Polygon([{
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }, {
    x: 0.5,
    y: 0.5
  }], {
    fill: fillColor,
    PolygonNumber: polygonCount,
    name: "Polygon",
    type: 'normal',
    noofcircles: ArrayLength
  });
  canvas.add(window["polygon" + polygonCount]);
  for (var i = 0; canvas.getObjects().length > i; i++) {
    if (canvas.getObjects()[i].polygonNo === polygonCount) {
      var points = window["polygon" + polygonCount].get("points");
      if (canvas.getObjects()[i].circleNo == 1) {
        points[0].x = canvas.getObjects()[i].left - window["polygon" + polygonCount].get("left");
        points[0].y = canvas.getObjects()[i].top - window["polygon" + polygonCount].get("top");
      } else if (canvas.getObjects()[i].circleNo == 2) {
        points[1].x = canvas.getObjects()[i].left - window["polygon" + polygonCount].get("left");
        points[1].y = canvas.getObjects()[i].top - window["polygon" + polygonCount].get("top");
      } else {
        points.push({
          x: canvas.getObjects()[i].left - window["polygon" + polygonCount].get("left"),
          y: canvas.getObjects()[i].top - window["polygon" + polygonCount].get("top"),
        });

      }
      window["polygon" + polygonCount].set({
        points: points
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; canvas.getObjects().length > i; i++) {
    if (canvas.getObjects()[i].name == "draggableCircle") {
      canvas.bringForward(canvas.getObjects()[i]);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
  polygonCount++;
  canvas.renderAll();
}

function Addpolygon() {
  startDrawingPolygon = true;

}
canvas.on('object:moving', function(option) {
  var startY = option.e.offsetY,
    startX = option.e.offsetX;
  for (var i = 0; i < canvas.getObjects().length; i++) {
    if (canvas.getObjects()[i].name == "Polygon") {
      if (canvas.getObjects()[i].PolygonNumber == option.target.polygonNo) {
        var points = window["polygon" + option.target.polygonNo].get("points");
        points[option.target.circleNo - 1].x = startX - window["polygon" + option.target.polygonNo].get("left");
        points[option.target.circleNo - 1].y = startY - window["polygon" + option.target.polygonNo].get("top");
        window["polygon" + option.target.polygonNo].set({
          points: points
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
      }
    }

    if (canvas.getObjects()[i].name == "draggableCircle") {
      canvas.bringForward(canvas.getObjects()[i]);
    }

  }
  canvas.renderAll();
})
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(option) {
  if (typeof option.target != "undefined") {
    return;
  } else {
    if (addTexture) {
      console.log(option);
    }
    if (startDrawingPolygon) {
      circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: canvas.getPointer(option.e).x,
        top: canvas.getPointer(option.e).y,
        radius: 7,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        polygonNo: polygonCount,
        name: "draggableCircle",
        circleNo: circleCount,
        fill: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        hasRotatingPoint: false,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
      });
      canvas.add(circle);
      canvas.bringToFront(circle);
      circleCount++;
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#backgroundCanvas {
  background-image: url('nike.jpg');
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button onclick="Addpolygon()">Add Polygon Points</button>
    <button onclick="done()">Create Polygon</button>
</div>
<div style="position:relative">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px" style="z-index:10;background-color:transparent;"></canvas>
    <div id="backgroundCanvas" style="width:400px;height:400px"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
objectCaching: false
```

It wont create a cache canvas for the object if this is disabled. And for polygon points I have taken circle left and top value.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var polygonCount = 1;
var startDrawingPolygon;
var ArrayLength;
var addTexture = false;
var circleCount = 1;
var fillColor = "rgba(46, 240, 56, 0.5)";

function done() {
  startDrawingPolygon = false;
  ArrayLength = circleCount;
  circleCount = 1;
  var tempCount = 0;
  var objects = canvas.getObjects();
  var points = [];
  for (var i = 0; objects.length > i; i++) {
    if (objects[i].polygonNo === polygonCount) {
      points.push({
        x: objects[i].left,
        y: objects[i].top
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  }
  console.log(points)
  window["polygon" + polygonCount] = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
    fill: fillColor,
    PolygonNumber: polygonCount,
    name: "Polygon",
    selectable: false,
    noofcircles: ArrayLength,
    objectCaching: false
  });
  canvas.add(window["polygon" + polygonCount]);
  canvas.sendToBack(window["polygon" + polygonCount])
  canvas.renderAll();
  polygonCount++;
}

function Addpolygon() {
  startDrawingPolygon = true;
}

canvas.on('object:moving', function(option) {
  var object = option.target;
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    if (obj.name == "Polygon") {
      if (obj.PolygonNumber == object.polygonNo) {
        var points = window["polygon" + object.polygonNo].get("points");
        points[object.circleNo - 1].x = object.left;
        points[object.circleNo - 1].y = object.top;
        window["polygon" + object.polygonNo].set({
          points: points
        });
      }
    }
  })
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(option) {

  if (option.target && option.target.name == "draggableCircle") {
    return;
  } else {
    if (addTexture) {
      console.log(option);
    }
    if (startDrawingPolygon) {
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(option.e);
      circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: pointer.x,
        top: pointer.y,
        radius: 7,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        polygonNo: polygonCount,
        name: "draggableCircle",
        circleNo: circleCount,
        fill: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        hasRotatingPoint: false,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
      });
      canvas.add(circle);
      circleCount++;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#backgroundCanvas {
  background-image: url('nike.jpg');
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button onclick="Addpolygon()">Add Polygon Points</button>
    <button onclick="done()">Create Polygon</button>
</div>
<div style="position:relative">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px" style="z-index:10;background-color:transparent;"></canvas>
    <div id="backgroundCanvas" style="width:400px;height:400px"> </div>
</div>
```